# How can I intercept what is being said to dictation on OSX 10.11

Tags: macos, applescript, dictation

I am using a MacBook Pro, Early 2011 running OS X El Capitan. They re-added the dictation feature which allows constant listening, which I have been using with Applescript (like "Computer, quit" and it runs the script). I would love to expand though.

My question: Where can I find what the computer is interpreting? I want to use the entire phrase, like "Computer, I want to listen to music" and have it search through that phrase for the keyword music (then open iTunes or something). This way, instead of having short commands like "quit" or "shut down" it can interpret sentences. Also, how would I create a program that continues to run in the background, searching for these keywords.

Thank you for the help (I am quite the novice),

rednaxelaf7